# How to stretch a bitmap in C and SDL?

Tags: c, bitmap, sdl, sprite

I am making a game for my CS class and the sprites I have found online are too small. How do you 'stretch' a bitmap... make them bigger using SDL? (I need to increase there size 50%, there all the same size.) A snippet of example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to get a better looking result using software that is designed for this task. A good option is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). It can be used from the command line or programatically.

For example, from the command line you just enter:

```
convert sprite.bmp -resize 150% bigsprite.bmp
```

---

If for some strange reason you want to write your own bilinear resize,  [this guy looks like he knows what he is doing.](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Bilinear_resize)

Comment: Thankyou, I appreciate the help plus the link for futher info.

Answer (score 4):

This question does not specify SDL version, and even though SDL2 was not available when the question was written, an SDL2 answer would add completeness here i believe.

Unlike SDL1.2, scaling is possible in SDL2 using the API method `SDL_RenderCopyEx`. No additional libs besides the basic SDL2 lib are needed.

```
int SDL_RenderCopyEx(SDL_Renderer*          renderer,
                     SDL_Texture*           texture,
                     const SDL_Rect*        srcrect,
                     const SDL_Rect*        dstrect,
                     const double           angle,
                     const SDL_Point*       center,
                     const SDL_RendererFlip flip)
```

By setting the size of `dstrect` one can scale the texture to an integer number of pixels. It is also possible to rotate and flip the texture at the same time.

Reference: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopyEx

Create your textures as usual:

```
surface = IMG_Load(filePath);
texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
```

And when it's time to render it, call `SDL_RenderCopyEx` instead of `SDL_RenderCopy`

Answer (score -1):

have you tried?

```
    SDL_Rect src, dest;
    src.x = 0;
    src.y = 0;
    src.w = image->w;
    src.h = image->h;
    dest.x = 100;
    dest.y = 100;
    dest.w = image->w*1.5;
    dest.h = image->h*1.5;
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, &src, screen, &dest);
```

Comment: SDL_BlitSurface doesn't stretch/scale. The the width and height of dest are ignored

Answer (score -1):

Use for stretch the undocumented function of SDL:
extern DECLSPEC int SDLCALL SDL_SoftStretch(SDL_Surface *src, SDL_Rect *srcrect,
                                    SDL_Surface *dst, SDL_Rect *dstrect);

Like:

SDL_SoftStretch(image, &src, screen, &dest);

Comment: That function doesn't actually exist.